# How to read 1 symbol in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I need to get exactly one character from console and not print it.
I've tried to use `read -en 1` as I did using bash. But this doesn't work at all.
And `vared` doesn't seem to have such option.

How to read 1 symbol in **zsh**? (I'm using zsh **v.4.3.11** and **v.5.0.2**)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
read -sk
```

From the [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html):

> -s
>
> Don’t echo back characters if reading from the terminal. Currently does not work with the -q option.
>
> -k [ num ]
>
> Read only one (or num) characters. All are assigned to the first name, without word splitting. This flag is ignored when -q is present. Input is read from the terminal unless one of -u or -p is present. This option may also be used within zle widgets.
>
> Note that despite the mnemonic ‘key’ this option does read full characters, which may consist of multiple bytes if the option MULTIBYTE is set.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your script to be a bit more portable you can do something like this:

```
y=$(bash -c "read -n 1 c; echo \$c")
```

Comment: This was helpful. I have a shebang of `/bin/bash`, but am running the script in zsh which seems to override the interpreter for just `read`. Here's a slight addition `choice=$(bash -c "read -p 'Are you sure? (y/n) ' -n 1 c; echo \$c")`.

Answer (score 3):

`read` reads from the terminal by default:

```
% date | read -sk1 "?Enter one char: "; echo $REPLY
Enter one char: X
```

Note above:

- The output of `date` is discarded
- The `X` is printed by the echo, not when the user enters it.

---

To read from a pipeline, use file descriptor 0:

```
% echo foobar | read -rk1 -u0; echo $REPLY
f
% echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
read line
c=`echo $line | cut -c1`
echo $c
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for me. User would have to enter a symbol (or line), then hit "Enter". I need to get this exact one symbol and move on. And, most important, this symbol need to be not printed.